# Fatal: pathspec 'file.txt' did not match any files, using git

Tags: git

I have started learning Git.
Now at the starting I got stuck with this error

Fatal: pathspec 'file.txt' did not match any files.

Here is the log and screenshot of my problem:

[image: screenshot]

```sh
ln: failed to create symbolic link /etc/atab': Permission denied
"C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts'> /etc/hosts'
/usr/bin/cp: cannot create regular file '/etc/hosts': Permission denied
'C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\protocol > /etc/protocols"
/usr/bin/cp: cannot create regular file '/etc/protocols': Permission denied
'C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\services > /etc/services'
/usr/bin/cp: cannot create regular file '/etc/services': Permission denied
'C:\Windows\system32\drivers etc\networks > /etc/networks
/usr/bin/cp: cannot create regular file '/etc/networks': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove /etc/post-instal1/01-devices.post': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove /etc/post-instal1/03-mtab.post': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove /etc/post-instal1/06-windows-files.post': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove /etc/post-instal1/99-post-install-cleanup.post': Permission denied

HTCODESKTOP-V8D4M7P MINGW64 - (master)
S git add index.html
fatal: pathspec 'index.html' did not match any files

HTCODESKTOP-V8D4M7P MINGW64- (master)
S^C

HTCODESKTOP-V8D4M7P MINGK64- (master)
```

Comment: Can you type `ls -la` to show what files are in that directory?

Comment: Hi, please can you click [edit] under your question and make it easier for people to help you. Firstly, please post commands and error messages as text, not images. Please also include more details about what you have tried so far - have you checked that the file exists?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure first you have not opened a git bash session from a CMD run as Administrator.

Its '`~`' (`$HOME`) would be `C:\windows\System32`, and nothing good would happen from a git repository initialized directly in `$HOME`.

Make sure to run your bash as a regular user, and initialize a new local repository using a folder name which does not yet exist, and will be created by [`git init`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init):

```
cd
pwd
git init myFirstRepo
cd myFirstRepo
```

Comment: thanku it's working now

Answer (score 0):

Try this - It worked for me

```
$ echo hello > index.html 
$ git add index.html
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).